# Extraction of Roads from a Large Geographical Dataset

Tags: data-mining

Google Maps API allows grabbing roads for individual latitude and longitude specifications (or the nearest roads if the point/s are not on a road). However, the way it requires data to be entered for each individual request makes finding a large number of roads very difficult (in my case ~17000). I was wondering if anyone knew how to automate the process to take a list of points and spit back the relevant roads (either in Google Maps or elsewhere)?

Comment: This does not appear to have anything to do with statistics.

Comment: I'd use OpenStreetMap. You can download large road datasets from them.